# How to completely uninstall Guix in Debian

Tags: debian, uninstall, guix

I installed Guix from the Debian main repository (`sudo apt-get install guix`). I want to uninstall it, so I ran `sudo apt-get purge guix` and `sudo apt-get autoremove`. However, it seems that Guix is still using up lots of space on my computer (e.g. `/gnu/store/` and `/var/guix/` are still full of files). How do I completely remove Guix?

Answer (score 0):

Since the packages have been purged, the files that remain are no longer registered by dpkg in the packaging system, in which case they can be removed without any consequences of note.

You can check whether dpkg sees any of the files with commands such as:

```
dpkg -S /var/guix/<file>
dpkg -S /var/guix
dpkg -S /gnu/store/<file>
dpkg -S /gnu/store
```

If dpkg doesn't identify a package to which they belong, then these files and directories can be removed with the `rm` command.

It's also possible to check what depends on guix on your system with:

```
apt rdepends guix
```

Likely nothing is found apart from guix itself.